# Will AWS Google SSO Integration kill the current AWS users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-workspace, google-sso

We are planning to integrate Google SSO to AWS but we have a fear that integrating Google SSO must not kill the current Administrator accounts.

Do anyone has any idea about it.

Thanks.